# VBA Access import Field doesn't exist in destination - Fieldname is garbled

Tags: ms-access, import, ms-access-2007, vba

I'm importing a *.csv file into an Access table with the following code:

```
Dim fd As FileDialog

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd

    If .Show = -1 Then

        DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acImportDelim, _
            TableName:="New References", _
            FileName:=.SelectedItems.Item(1), _
            HasFieldNames:=True

        TextReferenceImport = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    Else
        TextReferenceImport = ""
    End If
End With

Set fd = Nothing
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Microsoft Visual Basic
Field 'ï»¿Name' doesn't exist in destination table 'New references.'
```

Obviously, the field name in both Access and the *.csv file is "Name". This is also the first column of the *.csv file. I have also set **HasFieldNames** to False, and changed the first columns name to **F1** in access, and that seemed to work so I don't think there is anything wrong with the import.

Why does access read these strange characters that are not present in the *.csv or table, that then disrupt the import?

Comment: `.SelectedItems.Item(1)` is being utilized within a `With` statement I assume? Can you post the entire code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those `ï»¿` characters are the UTF-8 BOM ([byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)).

Unless it's practical to strip them out of your CSV before doing the import, I think you will need to create an Import Specification.

Begin an import manually from the Access user interface.  After selecting your CSV file, select *"First Row Contains Field Names"* from the second page of the *"Import Text Wizard"*.  Then click the *"Advanced"* button and select *"Unicode (UTF-8)"* for the *"Code Page"* property on the import specification dialog.  And then click *"Save As"* to give your import specification a name.

[image: Import Specification with Unicode (UTF-8) as Code Page]

Then you can use that saved import specification when you call `DoCmd.TransferText` from VBA.  Here is an example I tested in Access 2007 ...

```vb
DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acImportDelim, _
    SpecificationName:="YourTable Import Specification", _
    TableName:="YourTable", _
    FileName:="C:\Users\hans\Documents\YourTable.csv", _
    HasFieldNames:=True
```